# Permissions errors while using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am using `npm` inside a docker container with the user `root` however I am getting the two following errors:

```
glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
```

and

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/application/public/mix-manifest.json'
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/application/public/mix-manifest.json'
}
```

however root is the owner of the `.npm` and `.npm/_logs` folder:

```
~/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 25 09:12 .npm

~/.npm/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 09:18 _logs
```

and `root` has read/write access to the file `/application/public/mix-manifest.json`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data  119 Mar 15 14:26 mix-manifest.json
```

What am I doing wrong?

My Dockerfile contains:

```
# Node + NPM
RUN curl -kfsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: The npm bit is `RUN curl -kfsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs` but the whole file is here: https://pastebin.com/gqcVqAf8

Comment: Can you please add `RUN w` before this problematic `curl` and paste the answer here?

Comment: It returned a read error and a decompressionFailed on a package list, full error: https://pastebin.com/Re8fWTC1

Comment: Please edit the question and include these details in the question itself (not as links to somewhere else and not in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my dockerfile from

```
# Node + NPM
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

to

```
# Node + NPM
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

fixed the problem.